# Am I missing something, or do we have a couple inconsistencies / misnomers?

Tags: f#

Mathematicians typically count starting with 1, and call the counting variable `n` (i.e. "the nth term of the sequence). Computer scientists typically count starting with 0, and call the counting variable `i` (i.e. "the ith index of the array"). Which is why I was confused to learn that `Seq.nth` actually returns the "n+1 term of the sequence".

Doubly confusing is that `Seq.iteri` does as it's name implies and traverses a sequence supplying the current index.

Am I missing something? Is there a rational / history for this misnomer / inconsistency? Or was it just a mistake (which likely can't be fixed since we have a commercial release now).

**Edit**

Admittedly my claim about conventional use of `i` and `n` is not strictly true and I should have been more careful about such an assertion. But I think it is hard to deny that the most popularly used languages do start counting at 0 and that `i` and `j` are most certainly extremely popular choices for index variable names. So, when I am familiar with using `Seq.iteri` and `Seq.mapi` and then come across `Seq.nth` I think it is reasonable to think, "Oh, this function counts differently, probably the other way things are counted, starting with 1."

And, as I pointed out in the comments, the summaries for `Seq.iteri`, `Seq.mapi`, and `Seq.nth` only served to enforce my assumption (note that intellisense only gives you the summaries, it does not give you the description of each parameter which you have to find on MSDN):

Seq.iter

> Applies the given function to each
>   element of the collection. The integer
>   passed to the function indicates the
>   index of element.

Seq.mapi

> Creates a new collection whose
>   elements are the results of applying
>   the given function to each of the
>   elements of the collection. The
>   integer index passed to the function
>   indicates the index (from 0) of
>   element being transformed.

Seq.nth

> Computes the *nth* element in the
>   collection.

Note the emphasis on "nth", not mine, as if everyone knows what the *nth* element in the sequences is as opposed to the *ith* element.

Comment: If you really believe that there is any naming convention based on `n` versus `i` that everyone adheres to that distiguishes "1-based" from "0-based", then I have a bridge I'd like to sell you.  :)

Comment: @Brain, OK. Let's just say 80% of the time this is the convention I've encountered. However, most troubling here is that a single convention is not adhered to within the same API.

Comment: The convention is adhered to 100%.  The convention is "every letter, whether it be `n` or `i`, means 0-based".  Right?

Comment: Clever, but I'm not buying your bridge :)

Comment: I agree with Brian: the letter used is irrelevant.

Comment: Except, `Seq.iteri` and `Seq.mapi` both explicitly state that they are indexed based, and then we have `Seq.nth` which states "Computes the nth element of the collection"... surely this is confusing / misleading.

Comment: One should distinguish on type-level instead of name-level. Names can (and *should*) be irrelevant for assessing correctness, types give a *proof*. My solution: Type `Index` is 1-based, type `Offset` zero-based and both don't have implicit conversions to `int`. Or at least - as Scala people could argue - one had to bring one in scope explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talking of history, `nth` is zero based in Lisp, which is probably what the F# function is named for. See the [common lisp spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm#nth) for `nth`.

I haven't found your statement about `i` and `n` in mathematics to be true; usually n is the number of something rather than an index. In this case, it was the number of times to call `cdr` to get the next element.

Comment: Thanks for the historical insight, I'm not sure if we know this is exactly where F# got it from, but it's compelling. Reflecting a bit more, I suppose you are right that in general mathematicians are indifferent to to 0-based vs. 1-based counting. But my favorite subject is number theory where you often generate series in one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers. What really threw me off was the inconsistency of `i` vs. `n` in the `Seq` function names.

Comment: If you look for nth in the [OCaml List module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) and then the [Standard ML List structure](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html), I think it's reasonable to trace the name back to Lisp. By the way, my solution to the inconsistency is: Seq.nth is not very useful (it takes linear time), so I hardly ever use it, and therefore don't have to remember the name. :)

Comment: @Nathan, indeed, I only ran into this recently because I was comparing performance of two infinite sequences and using Seq.nth to force iteration.

Comment: @Stephen: Oops. Yeah, I forgot about the infinite sequence use.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indexed starting from 0 in many computer languages, but some languages start from 1 and some allow a choice.  Some allow the index range to be set as part of the array declaration, or even to be changed at runtime.

Mathematicians are as likely to start at zero as one, sometimes use other index ranges, and attach no particular meaning to the letters 'n' and 'i'.

The method names `Seq.nth` and `Seq.iteri` are poorly named.